# How to show this inequality using the binomial theorem?

Tags: inequality

I need a hint in proving this inequality for $ n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $.

I am trying to show that

$$ \displaystyle \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} < e $$ for any positive integer $n$ using the binomial theorem, and my definition of $e$ is $ e = \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{r=0} \frac{1}{r!} $.

So I have

$ \displaystyle {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1}{\frac{1}{n}} + {n \choose 2}{\frac{1}{n^2}} + {n \choose 3}{\frac{1}{n^3}} .... {n \choose n}{\frac{1}{n^n}} < e$

$ \displaystyle 1 + 1 + \frac{(n-1)}{2n} + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6n^2} + ...+\frac{1}{n^n} < 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + .... \frac{1}{r!}...$

$ \displaystyle  \frac{(n-1)}{2n} + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6n^2} + ...  +\frac{1}{n^n} <  \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} + .... \frac{1}{r!}...$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Where you say "So I have..." you really ought to say "So I want...".  You're trying to <em>show</em> that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < e$, so you can't assume it just yet.

Comment: Think, what grows faster: $n^n$ or $n!$?

Comment: @Alizter n! grows faster. I've not yet figured out how to use this fact. My thoughts are that the RHS will converge faster that the LHS, and the end terms will be less significant in terms of the value of the sum.

Comment: You pretty much had it... $n-1<n$,$(n-1)(n-2)<n^2$ and so on.